# How to create a pin checker

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and trying to create a pin checker. Iv'e done most of it, but Iv'e got a problem with trying to get the code to reject the users attempts to enter letters or a combination of letters and numbers, so the code treats it as a incorrect answer. My code just crashes if letters are entered. I tried removing the int before the input statement, which makes it reject letters like I want it to, but now longer accepts the correct code.

```
pin = {1111}  # Correct pin code

count = 1        # Count function to allow code to recongise restrict pin attempts to three and to terminate code if three incorrect pins are entered

while True:
    enter_pin = int(input("Enter your pin: ")); # Ask user for pin code
    if (enter_pin) in pin:
        print("")
        print("Correct pin")
        print("")
        print("Access granted")   # Grant access if correct pin entered
        break
    print("")
    print("Incorrect pin. Please try again")   # Repeat question and allow another attempt if wrong pin is given
    print()
    count += 1
    if count == 4:
        print("Incorrect pin entered three times, system locked")
        break
```

What I want:

Enter your pin: 46166

Incorrect pin. Please try again

Enter your pin: egsrgsd

Incorrect pin. Please try again

Enter your pin: 1111

Correct pin

Access granted

Answer (score 1):

You can use exception handling to write a function for entering the pin, where if there is an invalid input then it will try again (loops indefinitely until the `return ...` statement succeeded).  The `ValueError` is the exception which is raised when trying to convert non-numeric string into an int (which currently will cause your program to abort, when the `try` ... `except` is not used).

```
def get_pin():
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input("Enter your pin: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("you must enter a number")
```

Then when you are currently doing

```
    enter_pin = int(input("Enter your pin: ")); # Ask user for pin code
```

change it to call the function:

```
    enter_pin = get_pin()
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```py
pin = {1111}  # Correct pin code

count = 1  # Count function to allow code to recongise restrict pin attempts to three and to terminate code if three incorrect pins are entered

while True:
    try:
        enter_pin = int(input("Enter your pin: "))  # Ask user for pin code
        if not enter_pin in pin:
             raise ValueError("Incorrect PIN")
        print("")
        print("Correct pin")
        print("")
        print("Access granted")  # Grant access if correct pin entered
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print("")
        print("Incorrect pin. Please try again")  # Repeat question and allow another attempt if wrong pin is given
        print()
        count += 1
        if count == 4:
            print("Incorrect pin entered three times, system locked")
            break
```

Here you can catch the errors of entering the wrong pin, or entering letters.

Comment: *"Python’s assert statement is a debugging aid, not a mechanism for handling run-time errors."* https://dbader.org/blog/python-assert-tutorial. The idea of using an exception for dealing with an incorrect pin is a perfectly reasonable one, but is there another exception that could be raised here? Maybe also `ValueError`? Maybe a custom exception?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I updated the answer to avoid other people doing the same.

Comment: You've left the `assert` statement in.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `try` and `except` for this problem. What it means is that, it will execute the code in the `try` block first and if it encounters a problem, will go to the `except` block and execute the code in it.

In this case, we transfer this part of the code to the `try` block

```
        enter_pin = int(input("Enter your pin: ")) # Ask user for pin code
        if (enter_pin) in pin:
            print("")
            print("Correct pin")
            print("")
            print("Access granted")   # Grant access if correct pin entered
            break
```

And transfer the part of code to the `except` block when the input is wrong.

```
    print("Incorrect pin. Please try again")
    print()
    count += 1
    if count == 4:
        print("Incorrect pin entered three times, system locked")
        break
```

So the complete code would be this -

```
pin = {1111}  # Correct pin code

count = 1        # Count function to allow code to recognise restrict pin attempts to three and to terminate code if three incorrect pins are entered

while True:
    enter_pin = int(input("Enter your pin: ")) # Ask user for pin code
    try:
        if (enter_pin) in pin:
            print("")
            print("Correct pin")
            print("")
            print("Access granted")   # Grant access if correct pin entered
            break
        print("")
    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect pin. Please try again")   # Repeat question and allow another attempt if wrong pin is given
        print()
        count += 1
        if count == 4:
            print("Incorrect pin entered three times, system locked")
            break
```